# What is the best way to manage production assets/data in a version controlled environment?

Tags: git, version-control

I have a fairly simple set up for my Django sites.

- A local development copy
- A copy in a private BitBucket git repo
- A clone on from git the server
- A fabric file to tie this all together

For each site I have two things that I don't maintain in git: `/media/` (the stuff people upload in the live site, usually linked to the database) and the database (a sqlite3 file). I exclude this from git because I never want my testing work on my local copy of the data/media to be uploaded. If I do want that, I'll upload manually.

I'm quite new to `git`. I was using Bazaar in a direct local→production exchange but now I have BitBucket in the middle, I would really like to use them for off-site backups.

I know most people wince when they hear people saying that but it means I can give my client access to the BB repo so if I "ever get hit by a bus" (worryingly, my client's words), they have enough access to get a new server up and running. Due to my own paranoia, they don't have access to the production server at all, which I share between other clients.

#### I can live with you hating me for asking but I've got three questions:

1. Assuming I'm not going to listen, what is the best way to store backups in one direction inside a repo? I can script the backup-creation (create a new tar) but where do I store that in git?
2. Can I avoid downloading them to my local branch? It isn't the end of the world but these are already backups. I don't need a copy in every repo.
3. And if I want to rotate backups over, for example, 7 days, what's the best way to clean up the old backups, permanently? I gather that git would naturally keep a copy of obsolete backups even after I remove them from the live branch. I need a way of preventing that.

I am open to hearing alternate solutions but I am mostly interested to know if git can be twisted to my evil bidding. It's so versatile otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

'1' and '2' are semi-solvable. You're using bitbucket, yeah? Just create a new repo for backups. Problem solved and you only need to clone it down where you need it. '3' demonstrates that git might not be the right technology for what you want to do.

By definition, git needs to reach every previous state of every file in the commit history. You can get around it with commands like `filter-branch`... but why? Git goes far out of its way to preserve past states. That is its ethos. Scripting the erasure of backups every seven days in a git repository is much more trouble than using a technology better suited to your problem. How about an S3 bucket in Amazon's free tier? Give your client access with a properly configured IAM policy and the whole solution can be had for a fractional yearly price. And it's S3. It has 11 nines of integrity. Unless your sites are absolutely gigantic, you could hold months of backups for very little money.